# Is this hadith from Sahih Al-Jami' about people not tested wishing their skins were cut up authentic?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

Is this hadith which can be found in Sahih al-Jami' authentic:

> The prophet (pbuh) said "The people who were not tested in this dunya will wish their skins were cut up when they see the rewards for those who were tested"

Hadith no. 5484

Comment: We might need a full reference i only could find a hadith which is similar in Jami' at-Tirmidhi http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/36/100 and it has a totally different number!

Answer (score 2):

The ruling by at-Tirmidhi is *hassan* (Arabic: حسن) *gharīb* (Arabic: غريب). Ḥassan means its authenticity is not as clear as that of a ṣaḥīḥ (authentic, Arabic: صحيح) hadith, but sufficient for use as evidence apart from deriving rulings. Gharīb means it was narrated from one chain only, which is the case for this hadith.

The hadith you are asking about is:

> #### حدثنا محمد بن حميد الرازي ويوسف بن موسى القطان البغدادي قالا حدثنا عبد الرحمن بن مغراء أبو زهير عن الأعمش عن أبي الزبير عن جابر قال قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يود أهل العافية يوم القيامة حين يعطى أهل البلاء الثواب لو أن جلودهم كانت قرضت في الدنيا بالمقاريض
>
> Jabir narrated that the Prophet ﷺ said: "On the Day of Judgment, when the people who were tried (in this world) are given their rewards, the people who were pardoned (in life), will wish that their skins had been cut off with scissors while they were in the world."
>
> [Jami' at-Tirmidhi 2402](https://sunnah.com/urn/725770/)

In addition to Jami' at-Tirmidhi, it was documented in *Al-Sunnan al-Kubra* by [Al-Bayhaqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Bayhaqi) (hadith 6055), *Al-Mu'jam as-Saghīr* by [Al-Tabarani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Tabarani) (hadith 242), among others.

The narration chain for the first five layers is identical. At the sixth layer, 'Abdullah ibn Sahfī' at-Tabīb documented it through Ibrahīm ibn Muammad al-Faqīh, who is trustworthy, with the rest of the narration chain being identical to that of at-Tirmidhi, which was through Muhammad ibn Humaid al-Rāzī:

1. The Prophet ﷺ
2. Jābir ibn 'Abdullah al-Ansārī
3. Abu al-Zubair Muhammad ibn Muslim ibn Tadrus
4. Sulaimān ibn Mahrān Al-A'mash
5. Abu Zohair 'Abdul-Rahmān ibn Maghrā'
6. Yūsuf ibn Mūssa al-Qattān al-Bughdādī
7. Two narrators: (a) Muhammad ibn Humaid al-Rāzī (at-Tirmidhi chain), and (b) Ibrahīm ibn Muammad al-Faqīh (al-Faqīh chain).

The reasons for the hadith being hassan only, and not sahīh, are Yūsuf ibn Mūssa is considered good for hadith but not to the level of sahīh in terms of memorization, and Abu al-Zubair Muhammad ibn Muslim who occasionally omitted mentioning the full narration chain where he got his hadiths from.

Comment: I have my doubts that at-Tirmdihi used the terms gharib, Hassan and sahih with the meaning you are pointing at! As what we consider as established term definition isn't or wasn't until the 6th or 7th century!

Comment: @Medi1Saif — You may refer to [pp. 104-105](https://archive.org/stream/waq64594/17188#page/n103/mode/2up) of Quqa'id al-Tahdith for the words of al-Tirmidhi himself: _hassan_ does not include _hassan sahih_ (which was his terminology for _sahih_) for al-Tirmidhi. If you think I misunderstood the definitions, we can discuss in chat.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of this hadith. What is sahih al jama? Could you maybe write the name source in arabic? I donot understand this name al jama, i haven't heard of it. Maybe you mean al jami'? Meaning the other name of sahih al bukhari.

Anyway, I know of this hadith a well known hadith:

حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ حُمَيْدٍ الرَّازِيُّ، وَيُوسُفُ بْنُ مُوسَى الْقَطَّانُ الْبَغْدَادِيُّ، قَالاَ حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ مَغْرَاءَ أَبُو زُهَيْرٍ، عَنِ الأَعْمَشِ، عَنْ أَبِي الزُّبَيْرِ، عَنْ جَابِرٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ يَوَدُّ أَهْلُ الْعَافِيَةِ يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ حِينَ يُعْطَى أَهْلُ الْبَلاَءِ الثَّوَابَ لَوْ أَنَّ جُلُودَهُمْ كَانَتْ قُرِضَتْ فِي الدُّنْيَا بِالْمَقَارِيضِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَهَذَا حَدِيثٌ غَرِيبٌ لاَ نَعْرِفُهُ بِهَذَا الإِسْنَادِ إِلاَّ مِنْ هَذَا الْوَجْهِ ‏.‏ وَقَدْ رَوَى بَعْضُهُمْ هَذَا الْحَدِيثَ عَنِ الأَعْمَشِ عَنْ طَلْحَةَ بْنِ مُصَرِّفٍ عَنْ مَسْرُوقٍ قَوْلَهُ شَيْئًا مِنْ هَذَا

Translation:

Jabir narrated that the Prophet (s.a.w) said: "On the Day of Judgement, when the people who were tried (in this world) are given their rewards, the people who were pardoned (in life), will wish that their skins had been cut off with scissors while they were in the world." This Hadith is Gharib, we do not know of it with this chain except through this route.

Some of them have reported something similar to this Hadith from Al-A`mash, from Talhah bin Musarrif from Masruq.

This is from كتاب الزهد عن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم in the Jami` at-Tirmidhi. It is graded as hasan by darusalam.